# How to create a service account for Power Automate flows

Tags: office-365, power-automate, flow, azure-ad, service-account

I want to create many scheduled and automated flows for a client. Now as I know the power automate flows runs under the account which create it. So it is better to use a service account to create those flows.

So can anyone advice what are the properties that we need to have when creating this service account? As is the service account similar to regular user accounts?

Comment: Service account is like normal user account only, it is recommended to user never expire password policy/settings for this account so that no one need to login/update the password regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service accounts to use in Power automate flows are like a normal user accounts only.

However, it is recommended to use never expire password policy/settings for the service accounts so that no one need to login/update the password for such accounts regularly.

Also, service accounts will require licenses and permissions to data sources similar to normal user accounts.

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [Add users and assign licenses at the same time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/add-users?view=o365-worldwide)
2. [Set an individual user's password to never expire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/set-password-to-never-expire?view=o365-worldwide)
3. [Set the password expiration policy for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/set-password-expiration-policy?view=o365-worldwide)
4. [Create a Flow with Service account](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-a-Flow-with-Service-account/td-p/367151)