# Service account with MFA enabled , how to transfer the membership/ownership to the client after completing the project

Tags: office-365, power-automate, authentication, flow, power-platform

I am working on a project for external client >> and I needed to create some SharePoint lists, solutions & Power automate flows.

Now they gave me a service account username/password, and the account had 14 days before setting the MFA. so in the last 2 weeks I created the needed SharePoint sites & power automate flows. then I were asked by the system to set MFA >> so I scan the QR code and used my mobile to complete the MFA setup process. after that I noted the all the connections inside Power Automate stop working and I had to re-authenticate again. Now I finished my work, so how I can transfer the ownership of this service account to the customer? so they used their own mobile to verify the MFA request? and will this transfer of ownership breaks the power automate connections again?

What is the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage authentication methods in the user's account settings. From there they can remove your authentication method and add their own. It shouldn't break the flows but eventually the Power Automate authentication will expire and they will need to re-authenticate for the flows to work.

Comment: yes i know this will not break the flow,,, but the connectors will stop working and will need re-authntication.. am i correcT?

Comment: Probably not initially, but they will eventually need to re-authenticate

Comment: can you advice more on what you mean by `Probably not initially,`

Comment: As in, they probably won't have to re-authenticate straight away after changing the authentication method but I'm not sure. This is not SharePoint related, better check with the Azure AD documentation/Azure forums

Answer (score 1):

You can change the multifactor authentication settings from My account > Security info page for service account profile.

Go to Microsoft My account page using this URL: https://myaccount.microsoft.com/

You can find Security info page from left side navigation:

[image]

Using this way, you can transfer the ownership of this service account to the customer using customer information/mobile.

You can also follow the Microsoft official documentation if needed: [Change your two-step verification method and settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/change-your-two-step-verification-method-and-settings-c801d5ad-e0fc-4711-94d5-33ad5d4630f7)

---

Ideally, it should not break the power automate flow connections again. But in worst case if those connections breaks, you can have a screen share meeting with customer and guide them to fix the connections by signing in once from [Power Automate Portal](https://make.powerautomate.com/) > Connections page:

[image]

Also, I will suggest you to use service accounts with never expire password policy/settings as mentioned at: [How to create a service account for Power Automate flows](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307517/how-to-create-a-service-account-for-power-automate-flows/307530#307530).

Comment: so should i do the ownership transfer? or the IT admin can do it?

Comment: You have the service account credentials and current MFA access. So, you can do it easily by following above steps.

Comment: Hi @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, does my below response answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.